# Inline divs without spaces and have parent div render behind all

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get three divs in a horizontal row. Each div has a different height. I want their parent element(which is yellow). This is the closest thing I have:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="display:inline-table; background-color:red; width:50px; height:50px;">aaa</div>
    <div style="display:inline-table; background-color:green;">
       <div>bbbbb</div>
       <div>ccccc</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-table; background-color:blue;">ddddd</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UuZeM/1/

This is pretty much exactly what I want, but I don't know how to get rid of the space between the blocks.

I've also tried setting each element to "float:left" instead of "display:inline-table", and that's almost exactly what I want - but the parent with the yellow background then doesn't get drawn behind the elements for some reason (I want the parent to be drawn behind the elements):

http://jsfiddle.net/kbR8P/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using display:inline-block; will solve your problem.
If you want the yellow background to fill up 
        the entire width of the screen then try this ​[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbR8P/1/)

```
<div style="background-color:yellow; display:inline-block; width:100%;">
  <div style="float:left; background-color:red; width:50px; height:50px;">aaa</div>
  <div style="float:left; background-color:green;">
    <div>bbbbb</div>
    <div>ccccc</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; background-color:blue;">ddddd</div>
</div>
```

else You should try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbR8P/2/)

```
<div style="background-color:yellow; display:inline-block;">
  <div style="float:left; background-color:red; width:50px; height:50px;">aaa</div>
  <div style="float:left; background-color:green;">
    <div>bbbbb</div>
    <div>ccccc</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; background-color:blue;">ddddd</div>
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

add `margin-left: -5px` that moves the elements to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the containing (yellow) `<div>` in the second example (with the floats).

Answer (score 0):

`display: table-cell;` instead of `display:inline-table;`